# How to order modifier in spacer in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am using two Spacer to give space between view and give padding to bottom item. Now I want to combine both Spacer, but unable to understand how can I give in order. Can anyone guide me how can I achieve that.

```
Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            .padding(20.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ) {
        Text()
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Button() 
    }
```

Visual effect

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain visually what you want to do?

Comment: Why should you use 2 Spacer?

Comment: I used 2 spacer because when we used the application in smaller device it looks very tight to each other. So that's why I used 2 spacer. @GabrieleMariotti

Comment: @ArdaKazancı I added image please have a look

Comment: What's the point for Spacer with 20.dp height? First one should cover the space that is not used by Text and button?

Comment: @Thracian actually in smaller screen both Text and button will attach each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to give a vertical padding to the `Button` just apply `Modifier.padding(top=20.dp)` in the `Button` removing the 2nd `Spacer`.
No reason to use a `Spacer` with `height(20.dp)` when the 1st Spacer just covers all the space between the `Text` and the `Button`.

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxHeight()
        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        .padding(20.dp),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
) {
    Text("text")
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))

    //Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
    Button(onClick = {}, modifier=Modifier.padding(top=20.dp)){
        Text("Button")
    }
}
```

[image]